# MarkLogic using JavaAPI

Tags: java, marklogic

I have been trying a normal Java API using the same example as mentioned in this page. I had to download various JARs:

1. java-client-api-3.0.7.jar
2. slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
3. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar
4. jackson-core-2.2.0-rc1.jar
5. apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar
6. javax.ws.rs.jar

It still gives me `NoClassDefFoundError` on

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/HttpParams at com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.newClientImpl(DatabaseClientFactory.java:322)

My Code:

```
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import com.marklogic.client.document.*;
import com.marklogic.client.io.*;
public class JavaML {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Here");
    DatabaseClient client =
      DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
        "localhost", 8000,"admin", "######", 
        DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST);
    JSONDocumentManager docMgr = client.newJSONDocumentManager();
    docMgr.write("/afternoon-drink",
      new StringHandle("{name: \"Iced Mocha\", size: \"Grandé\", tasty: true}"));
    String doc = docMgr.read("/afternoon-drink", new StringHandle()).get();
    //System.out.println(doc);
  }
}
```

Run:

```
javac -cp .;%CLASSES% JavaML.java
java -cp .;%CLASSES% JavaML
```

%CLASSES% - path to all the jars mentioned above.

Please help - am I missing something? Or is it a mandate that I have to download all these JARs?

Comment: Are you attempting to maintain the dependencies manually and compile with hand-constructed javac commands? If so, your life would be made much easier if you would use a build/dependency management tool, such as Gradle, Maven, Ant/Ivy, etc. Not only will it download and automatically set your classpath, there are tools available to discover dependency conflicts. If nothing else, build a stub gradle or maven project, and list the dependencies to ensure you have a complete set of jars in your manually maintained directory set. But you should really consider leveraging tools for this.

Comment: @MadsHansen - Thank you. I now understood dependencies. It worked with maven.

Comment: I'm glad that you got it working with maven.  Please note also that the zip download also comes with all dependencies: http://developer.marklogic.com/products/java

Comment: It would be useful for @MadsHansen or Bharadwaj to state this as an answer and accept it, so that others will see how to address this question

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the error message that you are missing the **httpcore-4.1.jar**.

However, there are a number of other dependencies that you are likely to be missing as well.

If you are maintaining your own set of dependencies and building your classpath manually, then you should [download the Java API zip](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/java), which includes all of the necessary dependencies in the /lib directory.

However, it would be much easier if you were to use a build/dependency management tool, such as Gradle or Maven. If you have the Java API as a dependency, it will download all of it's dependencies and will compile your application with the necessary libraries on your classpath. It makes upgrades much easier, facilitates automation, and is a best practice in favor of manually collecting and organizing dependencies.